# Difficulty understanding how the following examples conform to the definition of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

As far as I understood, a random variable is a mapping from sample space to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose this mapping changes with time for a process, the process is called a stochastic process.

**Example 1**
Let's say my random variable is as follows
w=H == X(w,t)=cos(t)
w=T == X(w,t)=sin(t)
So I clearly see that the mapping itself is altered with time, and hence it is a stochastic process.

**Example 2**
Now I will use the example of a random walk on a ladder. Let's say that the random variable X(w) be as follows.

w--> person is on step 1 corresponds to X(w)=1
w--> person is on step 2 corresponds to X(w)=2
and so on.

Now I don't understand how this is a stochastic process. At each time stamp, the above-mentioned mapping will be the same. So how can we say that its random variable is time-dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stochastic process is a mapping from the time set $\mathbb{T}$ (usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{N}$) to the set of all random variables.

Your first example is trivial in the sense that we assign to each time only a fixed number (a constant random variable) so there is nothing random about it.

For your second example we can chose the time set $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{N}$ and define for each $t\in \mathbb{T}$ a random variable $X_t$ by setting $X_t(\omega) $ equal to the position of the person on the ladder after the person took $t$ steps for a given outcome $\omega$.

Then if $t \neq s$  $X_t$ and $X_s$ are also different since $X_t$ give us the position on the ladder after $t$ steps and $X_s$ the position after $s$ steps, which are not the same random variable.

**Edit:** To add some additional context to the question raised in the comments consider the following:

A coin being tossed once.
Then we can define the state space $E= \{H,T\}$ (coin lands Head or Tail). The state space becomes a measurable space with the obvious sigma algebra.
Now define a random variable $Z:E \to \{0,1\}$ by $Z(H)=1$ and $Z(T)=0$.

Now we consider a coin being tossed twice. Then the set of outcomes $\Omega$ for the two tosses is $ \Omega = \{H,T \}^2$.
So for example if the coin comes up head the first toss and tail the second then the outcome $\omega$ is $\omega = (H,T)$.
Again we use the obvious sigma Algebra.
For $i =1,2$ we can define a projection map  $P_i:\Omega \to E$ by setting $P_i (\omega) = \omega_i$ where $\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2)$.
So then $P_1$ tells us the outcome of the first toss and $P_2$ the outcome of the second toss.

Now we can construct a stochastic process on the timeset $\mathbb{T} = \{1,2\}$ by defining $X_1(\omega) = Z( P_1(\omega))$ and $X_2(\omega) = Z(P_2(\omega))$.
So $X_1$ is equal to one if the coin is head on the first toss and zero if the coin is tail on the first toss.
Meanwhile $X_2$ is equal to one if the coin is head on the second toss and zero if the coin is tail on the second toss.

Now it is true that both times the same map $Z$ has been used to define both $X_1$ and $X_2$ but they are still different random variables, since if we have the outcome $\omega = (H,T)$  (the first coin is head and the second tail), then $X_1(\omega)=1 \neq 0 = X_2(\omega)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not the same random variable" in the last line. Are two random variables, X(w)=1 for w=H, X(w)=0 for w=T and Y(w)=1 for w=H, Y(w) for w=T, not the same random variable? Isn't the mapping from sample space to R not same for X and Y? I agree that X and Y may have different probability distributions, but the mapping from sample space to R is still the same right?

Comment: @s0meb0dy How are $H$ and $T$ defined? I dont understand how $X$ and $Y$ are related to what i have written.

Comment: Let's say I give a person two coins. The coins need not be same or unbiased. I tell him to toss the coin twice. I tell him to follow the following mapping X(w)=1 for w=H, X(w)=0 for w=T and note down his result for the first coin toss. Similarly I instruct him to do the same using 2nd coin and follow the mapping Y(w)=1 for w=H, Y(w) for w=T while noting down the outcome for the second coin toss. The point I am trying to make is that your X_t is like my X, and your X_s is like my Y, right? So would you say X and Y are different random variables in this example, even if they follow same mapping?

Comment: @s0meb0dy i have updated my answer to include the coin toss example

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks!